# IEnumerable<ulong>.Max() and IQueryable<ulong>.Max() returns different result

Tags: c#, max, profile, iqueryable

I am new to Linq and trying to query an entity to get the `max()` value.

The `pdmDocDrawingNumbers` are 9999999, 524244222235, 1 and some others.

Only maxvalue0 has the correct value 524244222235.

maxvalue1 to maxvalue3 has the wrong result 9999999.

What is wrong with the query for maxvalue1 to maxvalue3?

```
protected override void OnButtonClicked(IClickContext context)
{
    IEntityContext entityContext = context.EntityContext;

    ulong maxvalue0 = entityContext.Documents()
                                   .Where(d => d.IsA("/Document/pdmDocType2DCADFile/"))
                                   .Select(d => d.Get<ulong>("/Document/pdmDocType2DCADFile/pdmDocDrawingNumber"))
                                   .ToList()
                                   .Max();

    ulong maxvalue1 = entityContext.Documents()
                                   .Where(d => d.IsA("/Document/pdmDocType2DCADFile/"))
                                   .Select(d => d.Get<ulong>("/Document/pdmDocType2DCADFile/pdmDocDrawingNumber"))
                                   .Max();
                                                  
    ulong maxvalue2 = (from document in entityContext.Documents()
                       where document.IsA("/Document/pdmDocType2DCADFile/")
                       select document.Get<ulong>("/Document/pdmDocType2DCADFile/pdmDocDrawingNumber")).Max();
                          
    ulong maxvalue3 = entityContext.Documents()
                                   .Where(d => d.IsA("/Document/pdmDocType2DCADFile/"))
                                   .Select(d => d)
                                   .Max(d => d.Get<ulong>("/Document/pdmDocType2DCADFile/pdmDocDrawingNumber"));                                                   
        
    this.Dialogs.Information("Max Drawing0 Number: " + maxvalue0.ToString());
    this.Dialogs.Information("Max Drawing1 Number: " + maxvalue1.ToString());
    this.Dialogs.Information("Max Drawing2 Number: " + maxvalue2.ToString());
    this.Dialogs.Information("Max Drawing3 Number: " + maxvalue3.ToString());
}
```

The entities `Documents` stored in the PDM System ProFile (https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/4153732/RWTrLvrZ?version=latest)

Thanks for your help!

**Edit1:** I have now tried to narrow down the problem further.

```
ulong maxvalue1 = ((IEnumerable<ulong>)(entityContext.CreateQuery<IDocument>().Where(d => d.IsA("/Document/pdmDocType2DCADFile/"))
                                          .Select(d => d.Get<ulong>("/Document/pdmDocType2DCADFile/pdmDocDrawingNumber"))))
                                          .Max();
```

Gives the correct result 524244222235

```
ulong maxvalue2 = ((IQueryable<ulong>)(entityContext.CreateQuery<IDocument>().Where(d => d.IsA("/Document/pdmDocType2DCADFile/"))
                                          .Select(d => d.Get<ulong>("/Document/pdmDocType2DCADFile/pdmDocDrawingNumber"))))
                                          .Max();
```

Gives the wrong result 9999999

So it looks like the difference is between IQueryable.Max() and IEnumerable.Max().

Maybe I am also using IQueryable.Max() in a wrong way.

**Edit2:** The request is converted from an appserver into a sql request to a mssql server. The appserver is closed source so I can't analyse what exactly happens.
However, the api has a function with which I can issue the sql query for certain statements.

This request:

```
entityContext.CreateQuery<IDocument>().Where(d => d.IsA("/Document/pdmDocType2DCADFile/"))
                      .Select(d => d.Get<ulong>("/Document/pdmDocType2DCADFile/pdmDocDrawingNumber"));
```

is converted by the app server into the following request:

```
SQL DrawingO Number: SELECT [eav].*

FROM (

SELECT

(tO).[1.#ID],

[tO].[1.4 TYPE],

[tO).[1.4c1]

FROM (

SELECT

(1.#1D] = [1.#.d].[DO_IDNR],

[1.4STATUS] = [1.#.stat_3].[SP_KENN],

[1.4#TYPE] = CAST (3 AS TINYINT),

(1.#VC] = [1.4.d].[DO_VERSIONCOUNT],

(1.4VI] = (1.4.d].[DO_VERSIONINDEX],

[1.41] = [1.4.dv_11).[DV_VSTL1]

FROM [dbo].[DOKSTAMN] AS [1.#.d]

INNER JOIN [dbo].[DOKVAR] AS [1.#.dv_11] ON (((1.4.d].[DO_DTNR] = 11) AND
((1.4.d].[DO_IDNR] = [1.4.dv_11].[.DV_IDNR]))

INNER JOIN [dbo].[SPERREN] AS [1.#.stat_3] ON ((10 =[1.#.stat_3].[SP_ART]) AND ((3=
[1.#.stat_3].[SP_OBJTYP]) AND ([1.#.d].[DO_IDNR] = [1.#.stat_3].[SP_OBJIDNR])))
WHERE ((1.4.d].[DO_DTNR] = 11)

) AS [tO]

CROSS APPLY [dbo].[PRO_TVF_AuthorizeProjectRole}((t0].[1.4ID], [tO].[1.4TYPE],
[tO].[1.4STATUS], 2) AS [1.#.auth_p]

WHERE (([tO].[1.#V1] = [tO].[1.4VC]) AND ([1.4.auth_p].[P01] = 1))

) AS[t1]

CROSS APPLY (

VALUES (([t1].[1.#ID], [t1].[1.4#7TYPE], ‘dv_11.DV_VSTL1;, CAST ([t1].[1.4c1] AS SQL_VARIANT),
NULL)

) AS [eav]([ID], [TYPE], [KEY], [VALUE], [CLOB])

ORDER BY

[t1].[1.4TYPE] ASC ,

(t1].[1.41D] ASC
```

**Edit3:**
Thank you!
It was the data type in the database.
The field:

```
"/Document/pdmDocType2DCADFile/pdmDocDrawingNumber"
```

is a string in the database.
I have created a new field:

```
"/Document/pdmDocType2DCADFile/pdmDocDrawingBaseNumber"
```

with the data type number.
With this field the function:

```
int maxvalue2 = entityContext.CreateQuery<IDocument>()
.Where(d => d.IsA("/Document/pdmDocType2DCADFile/"))
.Select(d=>d.Get<int("/Document/pdmDocType2DCADFile/pdmDocDrawingBaseNumber"))
.Max();
```

returns the correct result, like the variant that pulls all values from the database into a list and then evaluates them locally.

I guess using this version with pulling all strings from the database isn't good, because the datatype of the database isn't visible:

```
maxvalue0 = entityContext.CreateQuery<IDocument>()
.Where(d => d.IsA("/Document/pdmDocType2DCADFile/"))
.Select(d => d.Get<int>"/Document/pdmDocType2DCADFile/pdmDocDrawingNumber"))
.ToList()
.Max();
```

i suppose this would be better for clarity:

```
maxvalue1 = entityContext.CreateQuery<IDocument>()
.Where(d => d.IsA("/Document/pdmDocType2DCADFile/"))
.Select(d => int.Parse(d.Get<string>("/Document/pdmDocType2DCADFile/pdmDocDrawingNumber")))
.ToList()
.Max();
```

However, I think the sql server is faster at searching data. So I think a variant where the sql server does the conversion (if a string field is used) including the max() function would be better.
Unfortunately, I have not yet found a way to implement this.
Does anyone of you have any ideas?

Comment: Looks as if `.Max()` treats values as strings when not using `.ToList()`

Comment: Note that instead of the cast `((IEnumerable<long>)expression).Max()` you can also write `expression.AsEnumerable().Max()`.

Comment: I think depends on what is in "the other end" of the `IQueryable<>`. Linq can "target" different "providers". I suppose there is not an SQL database in the other end? When you do not enforce `IEnumerable<>`, the expression you write in C# is being translated into something (in another domain) which is supposed to do the right thing. In this case, it does not. Maybe there is something wrong/missing with the type in the source. When you use `.AsEnumerable()`, everything is pulled out from the source, and the aggregation (here, the max) is done by the .NET runtime.

Comment: Thanks for your answers! I have now tried to find out exactly what the appserver is doing in the background (see Edit2).
I suspect that IQueryable<ulong> is not sorted by d.Get<ulong>("/Document/pdmDocType2DCADFile/pdmDocDrawingNumber") but by ID. If I output all drawing numbers without sorting, 9999999 is also the first result.

Comment: @Rafalon If the underlying database stores the value as a string, and the queryable expression is passed to the same database for execution, and the interface layer that hydrates entity objects in memory does the conversion, then it is entirely expected that the results are this way. However, this information is not part of the question, and since the OP says the appserver is a black box, it might not even be openly available.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen that's right, I didn't say it wasn't expected behaviour :) though I should have explained better the difference between IQueryable and IEnumerable `Max` (as Jeppe did)